# Javascript code to AST representation as we do in babelTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Every time I want to modify, I have to write `` t.importDeclaration([t.importDefaultSpecifier(t.identifier(`${importcomponentName}`))], t.stringLiteral(`../components/${importcomponentName}`)) ``

It is just for an import statement. Eg. , if I want to generate a whole component, I have to write a lengthy code that is too long in a file and time-consuming. Do we have any short way to do this by some recursion or library or any tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel provides [`@babel/template`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-template) for this type of thing so you could replace

```
const decl = t.importDeclaration(
  [t.importDefaultSpecifier(t.identifier(`${importcomponentName}`))], 
  t.stringLiteral(`../components/${importcomponentName}`)
);
```

with

```
const decl = template.ast`
  import ${importcomponentName} from "${`../components/${importcomponentName}`}";
`;
```

Comment: what if I want to have a large string, suppose a whole component to pass in template. ast?

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit That's not something I'd usually expect to be injected, but what you insert is really up to you. If I were doing it, I'd probably write all that component code in some normal JS helper file, and then if injection is what you want, inject an import to that helper file and a call to the helper function to create the component.

Comment: we can do it with this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Loganfsmyth's answer, instead of using `@babel/template`, you can use `@babel/generator`:

```
import babelGenerate from '@babel/generator';

const decl = babelGenerate(
  `import ${importcomponentName} from '${`../components/${importcomponentName}`}';`
);
```

Comment: I find Loganfsmyth's answer flexible.